# Cannot get iTerm profile to switch back to shell using zsh

Tags: iterm

I have a couple of profiles set up in iTerm on my Mac, for accessing different local and remote machines.  The main purpose of the profiles is to change the colours so that it is immediately obvious which machine that current session is connected to.

Anyway, my default profile is for my Mac.  I use `zsh` here.  The main other machine I connect to is a remote Ubuntu box.  Both machines have Shell Integration installed.  Now, ssh-ing to this Ubuntu box from my Mac successfully changes the profile to the `ubuntu` profile, as the terminal prompt matches the pattern in `iTerm -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced -> Automatic Profile Switching`.  However, when I end the ssh connection, the `ubuntu` profile persists, even though the pattern no longer matches.  The description of the Automatic Profile Switching states:

> If the rule stops matching, the profile switches back unless the rule begins with "!".

I can't seem to figure out a pattern to match against the zsh terminal prompt, nor will it match against the username or host.  I've even tried the output of the `$PROMPT` variable.  I am stuck in the `ubuntu` profile until I kill the iTerm session.